# Подчинительный союз

Tags: союзы

*Помогите,пожалуйста разобраться с союзами."...,но иной бросался,обнимал и целовал,только для того и останавливал всю толпу...."  "ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ТОГО И" -это подчинительный союз или что-то другое?*

Answer (score 1):

Подчинительный союз нужно искать в сложноподчиненном предложении, а здесь скорее всего бессоюзное сложное предложение (вторая часть его: только для того (ОН) и останавливал всю толпу).

А союзами здесь служат *но* и *и*, а последнее *и* — усилительная частица.
*Только* — частица:

> ТОЛЬКО. I. частица... 2. Единственно, исключительно. Говорил т. о любви. Стремится т. к победе. Не любит т. вранья. Т. в деревне и отдыхаю. Люблю т. тебя. Не купил лишь т. из жадности. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A0%C2%BB%D0%A1%D0%8A%D0%A0%D1%94%D0%A0%D1%95&all=x))

Останавливался [для чего?] для того. "Для того" — обстоятельство цели.